# In VB.Net, trying to animate a vertical line that repeatably sweeps from left to right across a Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, animation, graphics, picturebox

in VB.Net, I have a picturebox containing a graph like picture that looks like a grid.  There are also various code drawn shapes in the picturebox that can be clicked by the user..   I'm trying to figure out a way of having a vertical line from top to bottom of the picturebox that moves across from left to right at a predetermined speed. I also need to able to determine when the line moved across a shape that he been clicked.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Many thanks.

I've solved the other problems mentioned and can produce a vertical line in the picturebox with simple code.  But I'm stuck on trying to animate the line.

Comment: Use a Timer to Invalidate the PictureBox and raise a Paint event. Each Tick, increment the X coordinate of the line you draw. That X value would be stored in a field so it can be accessed in both event handlers.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're drawing a line in the first place so we don't know whether you're doing that the right way to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a vertical line that moves from left to right and starts again once it makes a full pass:

```vb
Private lineX As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lineX += 5

    If lineX > PictureBox1.Width Then
        lineX = 0
    End If

    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                        New Point(lineX, 0),
                        New Point(lineX, PictureBox1.Height))
End Sub
```

The X coordinate of the line is stored in a field and that field is incremented on each `Tick` event of the `Timer`. The value is reset to zero once it reaches the right side of the `PictureBox`.

It's up to you what you set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to. A smaller value will obviously move the line faster. You can also vary the amount by which you increment the X coordinate. A smaller value will lead to a smoother animation. You'll need to balance those two values to get the speed and smoothness you want while not interfering noticeably with any other GUI operations.

Generally speaking, it is preferable to calculate the smallest area that may have changed on the control and specify that when you call `Invalidate`. The entire code in the `Paint` event handler is still executed but only the pixels within that area are repainted on screen and it's that last step that is the slowest part. I'll leave that as an exercise for you though. You would need to create the smallest `Rectangle` that contained both the old line and the new line so that area was repainted, erasing the old line and drawing the new line. At the point that the line reset to the left side, you could invalidate the whole control or you could call `Invalidate` twice - once for the old line on the right and once for the new line on the left. You can call `Invalidate` as many times as you like to repaint complex areas.

Comment: Many thanks, the line works exactly as envisaged.  However, when I add something else to the picturebox, that is also removed.  In my code, just as a test, I add a rectangle.  There would be a few of these in practice.  This is also removed with the Invalidate.  I'm sure this has to do with your last paragraph, but I'm struggling to understand it.

Comment: On thinking about it, I will also need to establish when the moving line runs across one of the shapes I've added afterwards.  Is there any way to make the new shapes persistent and recordable so that I can get when the points intersect ?

Comment: @user1377723, you are supposed to do all your drawing in the Paint event handler, not just the line. I'm guessing that you're calling CreateGraphics somewhere for the other shapes. That's wrong. NEVER call CreateGraphics. Do all your drawing in the Paint event handler and it all gets repainted every time. Draw the line last if it's supposed to be on top.

Comment: @user1377723, the subject of the intersecting shapes is a separate topic so you should post a new question. Show the minimum relevant code from this topic once you get it working properly.

Comment: @user1377723, an alternative that may or may not be appropriate is to draw the other shapes once on a Bitmap and assign that to the Image property. That will then be permanent and you only have to draw the line each time. There may be a number of reasons not to do that though.

Comment: Moving everything to the paint event handler combined with a list(of) worked perfectly. Many thanks.  I have the bitmap with the grid as a background and now can draw additional shapes with a mouse click that are persistent.  Now to start on establishing when the line crosses a particular point.  Many thanks again for the help.